# Systemd service not working with Java and Python

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot

I'm running my Discord Music Bot on a VPS, and to start the bot as the VPS does, I have a service called "bot.service" (located in /etc/systemd/system), which have the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=blah blah

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java /usr/java/Lavalink.jar #THIS SHOULD START FIRST
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/launcher.py #THEN THIS
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it doesn't work, the bot does not start as the VPS does. And yes, I've run this two commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable bot.service
```

If someone knows what it's happening, I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

Regards.

Comment: Does `journalctl` show any useful information? (`journalctl -u bot.service` to filter its output). What does `systemctl status bot.service` say?

Comment: I suspect both will be started simultaneously.  There is nothing in `man systemd.service` or `man systemd.exec` to suggest that it will wait for one to exit before the other starts or it will wait for one to be in some steady internal state before starting the other.  If `launcher.py` depends on `Lavalink.jar`, then it might be a better idea to split them into seperate services with an `After=` and perhaps `Requires=` relationship.  If `Lavalink.jar` implements `watchdog`, then this gets easy.  Otherwise, you might want an `ExecStartPre=sleep ...` for the `launcher.py` service.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect both `ExecStart=` commands will be started simultaneously. There is nothing in [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) or [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#) to suggest that it will wait for one to exit before the other starts or it will wait for one to be in some steady internal state before starting the other.

In fact, `man systemd.service` explicitly says this about `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecStartPost=`:

> Syntax is the same as for ExecStart=, except that multiple command lines are allowed and the commands are executed one after the other.

`ExecStart=` does say multiple commands are allowed with `Type=oneshot` but does not say that one will be executed after the other.

If you want `Lavalink.jar` to exit before starting `launcher.service` the answer is simple: Use `ExecStartPre=` instead of `ExecStart=` for `Lavalink.jar`.

Otherwise, if `launcher.py` depends on `Lavalink.jar` and they are long-running services, then it might be a better idea to split them into seperate services like so:

```
# lavalink.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/java/Lavalink.jar
```

```
# launcher.service
[Unit]
After=lavalink.service
Requires=lavalink.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/launcher.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't normally like `sleep` because on a slow-day, your second service might start too early, and on a fast-day, your second service isn't starting as soon as possible.

A better solution would be if `Lavalink.jar` implemented the watchdog.  Then you could use `Type=watchdog` in `lavalink.service`. That would cause `launcher.service` to start only after the watchdog starts receiving a heartbaeat from `lavalink.service`.   This would be a nice replacement for `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. "launcher.py" does not require the lavalink virtual server, but the bot itself does. That's why the Java server (Lavalink.jar) needs to start before the actual bot.

Comment: Great. That's even easier.  The 2-service technique still works, but you don't need any of those `Requires=`, `After=` or `ExecStartPre=` lines.  But you will want the `[Install]` section for both services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why python script does not start but you have to use the command:
`/usr/bin/java -jar path/to/jar/file`
to execute the `.jar` files.